# Javascript - Changing the display style of an object for a specific value of a property

Tags: javascript

As the title says, I need to change the style of a new object if one of the properties has a specific value. I cannot do that by defining another property with the style as, while I approximately know the property I am looking at and the characteristics of the value (will be regex), the objects will be dynamically created at some point from an external json file (haven't gotten to that part yet).

However, when I try to use an if statement in the display method of the constructor, the style of all the objects created based on that constructor take the last style defined.

The system I am working on does not support ANY type of frameworks, so the jquery solution will not be usable.

Code (I simplified the code for this problem)

```js
function standardBook(title, author, category, coverType) {
  this.title = title || "unknown title";
  this.author = author || "unknown author";
  this.category = category || "unknown category";
  this.coverType = coverType || "unknown cover type";
  this.display = function() {
    if (this.title == "Harry Potter") {
      msg.innerHTML += "<li> yet another harry potter book </li>" //just used this as an example to see if the statement works
      msg.style.color = "red"; //style change no. 1
    } else {
      msg.innerHTML += "<li>" + this.title + " - " + this.author + ", " + this.category + ", " + this.coverType + "</li>";
      msg.style.color = "black"; //style for the rest of the items. If i remove it, all items will be red. If I keep it here, all are black;
    };
  }
};

var book1 = new standardBook("Harry Potter", "JK Rowling", "fantasy", "hard cover");
var book2 = new standardBook("Lord of The Rings", "JR Tolkien", "fantasy", "ebook");


book1.display();
book2.display();
```

```html
<ul id="msg"></ul>
```

Comment: Of course all list items will have the same color, if you specify the color for the list itself. You want to specify it for the particular list item.

Comment: you are totally right. For some reason I've been complicating this unnecessarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning style to ul and not newly created li element. Please set style for li node. Sorry for typos answered from mobile.

Comment: this really should be a comment and not an answer